# NoneType returned in recursive call with lists involved

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want (for learning purposes, but please let me know if there is a built-in function that does this), to define a function that takes:

- Input: a list `[x_1, ... x_k]`
- Input: a number `n`

and returns a list of lists:

- output: `[ [x_1...x_n], [x_n+1,...m x_n+n], ......  [...x_k] ]`

which basically "splits" the input-list into lists of size `n`, (the last list is allowed to have smaller size).

Example 1: `f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],2) = [[1,2], [3,4] , [5,6], [7] ]`

Example 2: `f([1,2],2) = [ [1,2] ]`

Example 3: `f([1],2) = [ [1] ]`

Example 4: `f([]) = [  []  ]`

I tried to implement the function as follows:

```py
def split_in_pieces(l,n): # Split a list into a list of lists, each of size n (the last one can be smaller).
    if len(l) <= n: 
        return [l]
    else:
        tail = l[n:]
        recursive_result = split_in_pieces(tail, n)  # Recursively split the rest of the list.

        # Now return the list with the first element,
        # concatenated with the recursive result
        return recursive_result.insert(0,l[:n])
```

This code however does not work. If I try:

```
r = split_in_pieces(range(30),2)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Can somebody please help understanding what is going on?

thanks!

Comment: there is an exaple for a `grouper` in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that does pretty much what you want. it returns an iterator so you may have to wrap it in a `list` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `insert()` method modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. You need to return `recursive_result`:

```py
def split_in_pieces(l,n): # Split a list into a list of lists, each of size n (the last one can be smaller).
    if len(l) <= n: 
        return [l]
    else:
        tail = l[n:]
        recursive_result = split_in_pieces(tail, n)  # Recursively split the rest of the list.

        # Now return the list with the first element,
        # concatenated with the recursive result
        recursive_result.insert(0,l[:n])
        return recursive_result
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function (that I know of) that will do this. However, it's very easy to implement with a list comprehension - i.e., no need for recursion.

For example:

```
def split_in_pieces(lst, n):
    return [lst[offset:offset+n] for offset in range(0, len(lst), n)]
 

print(split_in_pieces(list(range(10)), 2))
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

**Note:**

If the modulus of the length of the list in relation to *n* is non-zero, this may not produce the desired result. For example:

```
print(split_in_pieces(list(range(11)), 2))
```

...would give...

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10]]
```

Comment: It would be nice to also include a test with a list where `len(lst)` is not a multiple of `n`, for instance `split_in_pieces(list(range(10)), 3)` or `split_in_pieces(list(range(11)), 2)`. Especially since the recipe `grouper`, that was suggested in another answer and comes from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), offers three different ways to handle that case, and none of the three options give the same result as the list comprehension.